# How to give custom size to PdfSharp generated Pdf

Tags: c#, html-rendering, html-renderer

I was trying to generate a pdf from HTML which containing a table using PdfSharp and HTMLRenderer. The following shows the code.

```
            pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PageSize.A3);

            byte[] fileContents = null;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdf.Save(stream, true);
                fileContents = stream.ToArray();
                return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(fileContents.ToArray()), "application/pdf");
            }
```

Is there any possibility for me to provide a custom size to the PDF and change the orientation of the page. I am using a memory stream to show the PDF directly on the browser display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PdfGenerateConfig` parameter of the `GeneratePdf` method to specify a custom page size using the `ManualPageSize` property.

Use the `PageOrientation` to get standard page sizes in landscape.

Code from comment:

```
var config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
config.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
config.ManualPageSize = new PdfSharp.Drawing.XSize(1080, 828);

pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, config);
```

Comment: var config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
                config.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
                config.ManualPageSize = new PdfSharp.Drawing.XSize(1080, 828);

Comment: PageOrientation is now a private member now, no way to set it anymore.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme It is public in the "official" version on GitHub and hasn't changed since 2015: https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer/blob/master/Source/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/PdfGenerateConfig.cs#L83

Comment: @Ballyoleidjit You're right, for some reason I had an outdated version.

Answer (score 1):

I just put this way:

```
var config = new PdfGenerateConfig()
{
    MarginBottom = 100,
    MarginLeft = 20,
    MarginRight = 20,
    MarginTop = 100,
    PageSize = PageSize.A4
};         

PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, config);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, PageSize.A3 is not an enum but Rectangle value. So instead of passing predefined Rectangle you can provide your own, for example:

new Rectangle(1191, 842) // for album A3

new Rectangle(842, 595) // for album A4

and so on...